# How to install cuDNN V5 for cuda 8.0 with NvidiaGeForce 1080 ti ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda

I installed CUDA 8, and I want to install cuDNN v5.
I downloaded the files from nvidia website, copied to the matching location in my cuda directory(*cudnn.h* to include, and *libcudnn** to *lib64*)
Also exported *PATH* and *LD_LIBRARY_PATH* to include and *lib64* respectively to my CUDA directory in *bashrc* file.

**Is there anything more I should do to install cuDNN v5 ?**

I ask because I see on the [installation guide](http://developer2.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v5/prod/cudnn_install-8.txt?NyQBTO7L-3Ae8srrvgtG7VOop290s96fYRAE0BhqY0Jw8_FMNjuXLAMCLVSy3HUDa29u1LjQzDDXILVGReSGny6GaLJcSFXfn0qExsQfAafMkG187MlDqWepnHo_rJ4qZc7T7oxJd8iZzQ1iGzldDHmATI_hj-HAR4sTQrGWP9Q) that I should do the following and I don't know what it means:

```
cd <installpath>
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Add <installpath> to your build and link process by  
    adding -I<installpath> to your compile
line and -L<installpath> -lcudnn to your link line.
```